# I am trying to set up budget action through the Budget of Cloud Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to set up budget action through the Budget of Cloud Formation.

When establishing the Budget on AWS managed console, it requires me to set the budget action, where I register role and user.
However, the budget section of Cloud formation does not seem to have this part where I need to register the role and user.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqDUG.png)

Answer (score 1):

[AWS Budgets Actions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws-cost-management/get-started-with-aws-budgets-actions/) are **not yet supported** in CloudFormation. The only way to use them in CFN, is by means of [Custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).

Thus you would have to develop such a resource in the form of a lambda function. The function would use AWS SDK's [create_budget_action](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/budgets.html#Budgets.Client.create_budget_action) to setup your action.